# How can I limit the number of user tries in this guessing game?

Tags: python

I have this code for a guessing game:

```
 import random

 

     def guess(x):
         random_number = random.randint(1,x)
         guess = 0
         while guess != random_number:
             guess = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {x}: "))
             if guess < random_number:
                 print("Too low, try again! ")
             elif guess > random_number:
                 print("Too high, try again")
    
         print(f"You got the number {random_number} correctly" )
      guess(50)
```

But I get an error that says:

```
def guess(x):
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'while' statement on line 537**
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Just how many lines are there in your program? Can you show the while loop before your ‘guess’ function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put something like `num_guesses = 0` at the top of the function, then at the end of the `while` loop put in `num_guesses += 1`, then at the start of the loop put in something like `if num_guesses < max_guesses:` and have that print something and `return`. `max_guesses` can be a local or global variable, or you could make it another argument and pass it in.